# grafana with sharded influxdbs?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I've been investigating the use of influxdb for storing our metrics.
Seeing that influxDB does not offer a clustered (free) version, I see there is an 'alternative' of using influxdb-relay, which can handle both replication and 'write-sharding'.

But the relay does not handle read queries.

In Grafana you can define multiple data sources which each pointing to specific shard, but from what I can tell it cannot combine the results form the shards into 1 data series.  (I know graphite has 'web-master', that does just this, it will query multiple graphite-web instances and combine the results prior to rendering)..is there such beast out there for grafana/influxdb?

If not how difficult do folks thing it would be to update to influxdb relays to accept queries, and query all shards matching the query/merging the results, etc.  yeah..I know depending on the query the merge actions would likely require query interpretation, which is where it gets difficult.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure I follow what the problem is.

Comment: If data is sharded out to multiple influxdbs using the influx-relay, then each shard will have different data.  But since read queries are issued against the lb, the read query will only hit 1 shard, as such it will miss data in the other shards.

In graphite-web-master (or what ever its called), it will in fact issue multiple read queries against all other subordinate graphite-web instances (each sitting in front of other whisper-dbs) i.e. it will query all 'shards', and then merge the data together for presentation, ensuring you have all the data in the results.

Comment: InfluxDB relay will split writes to all of the InfluxDB instances. So each instance should have the exact same copy of the data and thus you should be able to query any of them for the complete dataset. I don't see why merging is necessary. You could put all of the instances behind a load balancer and then add it as a datasource in grafana.

Comment: The relays can shard, so that not all the data is on all nodes (at least that's my understanding), i.e. lets say we want 10 influxdbs running, but only want 2 copies of the data..my understanding is that that you can shard it out so that this can happen, which means not all instances will have the same data.   (Hence..the reason for paid influxdb cluster, which allows users to provide replication counts when defining the db schema).  But since the query only hits 1 node..it won't see all the data.

Comment: From the Documentation on the relay: It's possible to add another layer on top of this kind of setup to shard data. Depending on your needs you could shard on the measurement name or a specific tag like customer_id. The sharding layer would have to service both queries and writes.

As this relay does not handle queries, it will not implement any sharding logic. Any sharding would have to be done externally to the relay.